# Possible to disable GWT EntryPoint during runtime?

Tags: gwt, entry-point

In my GWT 2.5 application, I got two entry points. EntryPoint A is the main application and EntryPoint B provides a widget version of my application.

Depending on a startup parameter, which I supply to the container, I want to enable/disable EntryPoint B. How can I achieve that? I know how to disable an EntryPoint completely during compile time by removing the correspondig declaration from my *.gwt.xml file.

Comment: Can u tell me how you are passing startup parameter to Container and what is that container?

Comment: Very simple, I e.g. use system variables, which I can retrieve via System.getProperty. Also, I have defined a GWT RPC interface to transfer those values to the client if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you could create two modules, where each provide a different entry point. Both would inherit from the common logic module. Each then has a different boostrap JavaScript URL (the .nocache.js). Disadvantage is that those will be completely different scripts to browser, so no caching benefits if you switch between widget and full version.

You can also do simple test within entry point method whether the entry point should be executed - just return if not. You can for instance check whether expected container element exists in DOM, or URL, or whatever. There is no much problem if two entry points are executed in a single module.

Comment: I decided to follow your second paragraph and just return from the on module load method in case I don't want to proceed. It is simple and works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

An GWT application can have only one Entrypoint.
So instead of 2 Applications you can  create 2 containers say ContainerA and ContainerB. In Entrypoint's onModuleLoad method you do an RPC call to fetch the Container deciding parameter. And based on the parameter you do

```
public void onModuleLoad()
{ 
      getRPCService.getStartUpParameter( AsyncCallBack<Parameter>
      { 
             public void onFailure()
             {
             }

             public void onSuccess(Parameter parameter)
             {
                   if( ContainerARequired( parameter ) )
                   {
                          RoolLayoutPanel.get().add( ContanerA )
                   }
                   else
                   {
                          RoolLayoutPanel.get().add( ContanerB )
                   }
             }
      });
}
```

With this method your js size will increase. So use code splitting and Run Async concepts to split the big js file in to smaller ones. And with this you can load only required js in to the browser.

Comment: Any number of entry-point classes can be added, including those from inherited modules. Entry points are all compiled into a single codebase. They are called sequentially in the order in which they appear in the module file. So when the onModuleLoad() of your first entry point finishes, the next entry point is called immediately.  https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects

Comment: Yes. This is also nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

In your `gwt.xml`

```
<define-property name="disableEntryPoint" values="true,false" />

<!-- Provide a default -->
<set-property name="alternateFeatures" value="false" />


<replace-with class="com.example.EntryPoint1">
  <when-type-is class="com.example.EntryPoint2" />
  <when-property-is name="disableEntryPoint" value="false" />
</replace-with>
```

Refer this :http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/ConditionalProperties

Comment: Just for my understanding: I thought the *.gwt.xml files are only relevant during compile time, but not during runtime? Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: You are correct. *.gwt.xml is a configuration file used during GWT compilation and for translating java to js.

Comment: The code will compile as per the information provided in gwt.xml* file. Once the code compile you can't change it, because its convert into java script. You can do something  just before the compile only (as per my knowledge its almost impossible to change a Entry point class at run time).

Comment: @Adarsha yes. Its already compiled to JS,Then how come classes there at runtime ??

Comment: Yes, I know how to do it during compile time, but I need this during runtime. Otherwise, I have to create two different artifacts (with and without widget war), which is too much overhead for the deployment scenario I'm working in.

Comment: @Suresh atta : which classes you are talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe, it's better to have one application by own one entry point.
in result, you will have 2 modules with own context and access paths:

- */entryA*
- */entryB*

also, two files:

- *EntryA.gwt.xml*
- *EntryB.gwt.xml*

those will include common stuff from *Application.gwt.xml*

Comment: Yeah, I need the decision during runtime and not compile time!